# $@Html.DisplayFor( is giving me a number on a table, I want to use that number so that an IF gives me that value

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

this is my code, I'm using a table and that table is giving me a certain number, lets say, 1000, in my if, I want to be able to use that stored number so that when I click the button my variable ('total') would be 1000, I'm not sure how to get it, I've tried item.Salario, Model.Salario and it won't work, I don't know if it's even possible

```
@model IEnumerable<Planilla.Models.Planillas>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Planillas</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Agregar Planilla", "Nuevo", null, new { @class = "btn btn- 
success" })
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Empleado.Nombre)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salario)
    </th>


    <th></th>
</tr>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empleado.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salario)
        </td>


        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Modificar", new { id = item.id }, new 
 { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |

                <button onclick="myFunction()">Calcular </button>

                <p id="demo"></p>

                <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                        var Salario = item.Salario;

                      var total = Salario;
                        var mtotal;
                        if (total >0) {
                            mtotal = "su total es " + total;
                        } else {
                            mtotal = "Salario tiene que ser mayor que 0";
                        }
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mtotal;
                    }
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Basically

```
   $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salario)
```

Is giving me a certain number, I want to display that number onto
my if in the following part

```
function myFunction() {
                        var Salario = item.Salario;
```

So that when I click the button I will get the number that item.Salario gives me on the table.

How do I do that?

Comment: You should use `@` prefix, e.g. `var Salario = @item.Salario;`. If you want to take its value from an element, put an id to `item.Salario` and use `$('#targetId').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues I noticed in your code.

First of all, you have the `p` element with `id="demo"`, which is inside your loop. That means your code will generate more than one `p` element with the same `Id` attribute value. That is invalid HTML markup! Id's should be unique.

You are also defining the `myFunction` function definition inside the loop! Run your code and check the view source of the page and see that is what you want. Do we need to define N number of times this method ? The behavior is same for all your rows, only the value of `Salario` is different :)

What you could do is, you may keep the value you want to pass in HTML5 data attribute of the button and then wireup the click event on the button using unobtrusive JavaScript. When the button is clicked, you can use `this` to get a reference to your clicked button, read the value from data attribute and use it for you calculation. To update the `p` element for the current row, you can use relative methods like jQuery `closest` method and `find` method.

Here is a working sample which uses jQuery library for DOM manipulation.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empleado.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salario)
        </td>
        <td>
              <button data-salario="@item.Salario" calculate>Calcular </button>
              <p result></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

You can see that I have set `data-salario` attribute on buttons and it's value is the `Salario` property of the item. I also added a `result` attribute to the `p` tag which I will use for getting that element in my jQuery selector (some people like to add a css class for this, but I do not). I did the same thing for the button as well (Added a `calculate` attribute, but we can use the `data-salario` attribute as well.

```
$(function () {

    // Listen to the click event of any buttons with a `calculate` attribute
    $("button[calculate]").click(function (e) {

        var $this=$(this);

        //Read the value from hml5 attribute
        var value=$this.data("salario");

        var mTotal="Total : "+ value;
        // you can add if your IF condition here to update mTotal 

        // First get the outer TD,
        // Then get the p tag with result attribute
        // Then update the text with your mTotal variable value
        $this.closest("td").find("p[result]").text(mTotal);

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, although I'm having trouble integrating that with my code, is it possible for you to just write up how it should be? Excuse me for asking

Comment: What trouble are you having  ? I did write up the issue with your code and the solution to fix that. That is the answer :)

Comment: to be honest i don't know if i should copy paste everything (or where) or if i should adapt this to what i have lol

Comment: Read the first code snippet above and make that change your view code. the second part is the Javascript, which needs to be included in your page after jQuery script is included.

Comment: how do i include jquery?

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics of  HTML before trying to build MVC web apps.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, thanks for your help, will takes this to my teacher and hopefully I can learn some more. Have a good one